# Importing bower component library into Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

I am working on an Angular 2 application in ASP.NET Core and I am trying to import oidc-client (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) into one of my Typescript files.  The oidc-client files were installed via bower which placed them in the expected bower_components folder.  The oidc-client.js file is copied to the lib folder under wwwroot via a gulp task on build.

My directory structure looks like this (only relevent portions represented):

```
wwwroot
|
 --app
|  |
|   --shared
|     |
|      --auth
|        |
|         --token.service.ts
 --lib
|  |
|   --oidc-client
|     |
|      --oidc-client.js
|
 --bower_components
|  |
|   --oidc-client
|     |
|      --dist
|     |  |
|     |   --oidc-client.js
|      --oidc-client.d.ts
|
 --typings
   |
    --index.d.ts
```

I need to use the oidc-client library in my token.service.ts file so I am doing this:

```
import { Oidc } from './lib/oidc-client/oidc-client';
```

But this results in an error 'Cannot find module './lib/oidc-client/oidc-client'.

I've tried different variations on the path, relative and non-relative, and I can't seem to figure out how to import the oid-client library.

Maybe its the typings not working?  Do I need to do anything special with the d.ts file to make it work?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use npm packages instead.  Angular 2 explicitly depends on NPM packages.

Comment: Ok, but the same question still exists.  Regardless of whether it came from an npm or bower package, I still can't seem to get the syntax correct to import it from my lib folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment made above, using the NPM distribution of `oidc-client` would be the preferred option.

However, the typings that are included in the `oidc-client` are a little strange. Usually, the typings `.d.ts` file sits side-by-side with the `.js` file. With `oidc-client`, they are in different directories and that's what's causing problems with your `import` statement.

If you install the NPM module and add `node_modules/oidc-client/oidc-client.d.ts` to the `files` configuration of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "files": [
        "index.ts",
        "node_modules/oidc-client/oidc-client.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

You should be able to create an `index.ts` file that imports `oidc-client`:

```
import { OidcClient } from "oidc-client";
```

If the `.d.ts` file and the `.js` file had been side-by-side, your `import` would have worked, but they are not, so it doesn't.

If you do not want to use the NPM distribution, it is likely that the separation of the `.d.ts` and `.js` files is what's causing the problem with the Bower distribution, too.

Comment: I went ahead and switched to the npm package as suggested.  Interestingly enough, the separation of .d.ts and .js still exists in that package.  My Angular 2 project started from the quickstart here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html so a typings folder already exists with an index.ts file.  All I needed to do was add the reference to that index.ts file like this /// <reference path="../node_modules/oidc-client/oidc-client.d.ts" /> and everything started working.  No need to update tsconfig.json.  Thanks for the help.